# Error! The requested URL did not return JSON asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have been using Telerik controls, I was using server binding, but I have to use Ajax binding, that is not working properly, I am getting Error "Error! The requested URL did not return JSON asp.net mvc"
Following is the Code in My Controller

```
[GridAction]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Contact model = _cService.getContact(id, applicationID);
        GetContactType();
        if (model != null)
            return View(model);
        else
        return View();
    }


    //
    // POST: /Contact/Edit/5
    [GridAction]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Contact model)
    {
        try
        {
            _cService.SaveContact(model, applicationID);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

and following Code in my view

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Contact")
          //  .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
   .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))

    .DataBinding(dataBinding => 
    {

        dataBinding.Ajax()

        .Update("Edit", "Contact", new { mode = GridEditMode.InForm, type = GridButtonType.Text })
        .Delete("Delete", "Contact", new { mode = GridEditMode.InLine, type = GridButtonType.Text });
    })
```

What I can do this Error, this error arise using Alert box, I have tried Modifying telerik.grid.min.js I have removed the line that shows an alert box,then it does not shows me error but also does not work. 
Can somebody please give me Some suggestions.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This is not a prompt response but as I'm addressing this issue now I can answer it. This is likely caused by the fact that your session has timed out, resulting in IIS to redirect to your login page. As it's the login page which is being returned, not the expected JSON, you get this message. You can trap for this error as follows:

```
var checkForSessionTimeout = function (e) {
    logOnResponse = e.XMLHttpRequest.responseText.match(/.*<title.*>(Log On)<\/title>.*/);
    if (logOnResponse.length > 0 || e.XMLHttpRequest.status === 401) {
        alert("Your session has expired. You will be redirected to log on.");
        location.href = logOnUrl;
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll have to define `logOnUrl` to point to your page.

A follow on question, should you have found the answer on your own, any idea how to prevent the actual error alert since we're providing our own?